# Text color for select and input

Tags: html, css

This is driving me nuts. I have a form where I have set the text color to be purple, but for some reason the select text is "stronger" than the input text. Can't figure out why!

http://jsfiddle.net/ZtyHS/

Any suggestions?

My CSS:

```css
.formBox, .normSelect {
    color: purple;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 6px 8px 5px;
    outline-color: transparent;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px; 
}
```

Comment: And by stronger, you mean darker  :)

Comment: What's "stronger" about it?

Comment: Oddly, as you type a value in the input, it becomes the same purple value. Probably to do with placeholder values.

Comment: A suggestion : go back to school and don't leave your day-job. It's the 'placeholder' browser default styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is the `placeholder`, which is the text shown when no value is entered. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/ and [Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css) explains how to style the `placeholder`:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    #999;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color:    #999;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color:    #999;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color:    #999;
}
```

Comment: Oh interesting! I thought that was going to be it, but if I did it correctly I'm still seeing a different "saturation" on the select values. http://jsfiddle.net/ZtyHS/3/

Comment: I do not suggest using browser prefixes.  Progressive enhancement is the way to go.   http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder

Comment: Is it better to just go back to using "value" instead of "placeholder" then? These values have to show up in all browsers, otherwise the user won't know what to put in what box.

Comment: No, placeholder is fine. If you need to support all browsers you can use plugins like https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Answer (score 0):

If you type in the field, you'll notice your input is the same color as the select box text.  What's the difference?  It's *placeholder text*.  See this answer for a much better explanation than I can give on placeholder styling:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2610741/495935

Answer (score 0):

If you were talking about "Select" text then adding this will work !

```
 font-weight:100;
 font-size: 12px;
```

sroes has mentioned for placeholder !

Answer (score 0):

This is what firefox will do to a 'placeholder' text

```
input::-moz-placeholder, textarea::-moz-placeholder {
  display: inline-block !important;
  opacity: 0.54;  /* <-- SEE THIS ? */
  overflow: hidden !important;
  pointer-events: none !important;
  resize: none !important;
}
```

Each and every 'supportive' browser will style by default.

See http://blog.ajcw.com/2011/02/styling-the-html5-placeholder/

[image]

Use [sroes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616859/sroes) answer to style your input[placehorder] and you should be ok.

Finaly, to answer your question 'Any suggestions?' : well, yes i have one : let's play chess or parcheesi.

Comment: Why would they make input text have opacity and not select text? That's just weird to me.

Comment: We are taking about the 'pseudo' element inserted has a temporary text inside an input[text] or textarea[text] and not a select[text] witch is not displaying a 'pseudo' element but real data from within the html.